# How to auto scroll a UICollectionView inside a UITableView using Timer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want my banners in my application to auto scroll using timer. I can perform scrolling if the collection view is alone but i don't know how to perform it when my collection view is inside a tableview.

```
var r = 0
let t = Timer.init(timeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    let index = IndexPath(item: r, section: 0)
    cell.cltView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .left, animated: true)
    if r == 6 {
       r = 0
    }else {
       r = r+1
    }
}
```

i am using this code inside cellForRowAt indexPath but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer has only initialised now, not used yet. To begin the process you need to add :-

```
t.fire()
```

Comment: i have that but its not working i just want to know where should i place this code. i have tried cellForRowAt and cellForItemAt both of them does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved my goal by creating a function and then calling it on cellForItemAt
and it solved my problem.

```
func scrollCollection(cltView: UICollectionView) {
    var r = 0

    let t = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        print(r)
        let index = IndexPath(item: r, section: 0)
        cltView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .left, animated: true)
        if r == 6 {
            r = 0
        }else {
            r = r+1
        }
    }
    t.fire()

}
```

this is the function i used and i just called it

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

let mainImg = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIImageView

mainImg.image = UIImage(named: banners[indexPath.item])
if op {
    scrollCollection(cltView: collectionView)
    op = false
}

return cell
```

i put a check marker so that i don't call it again and again.

Comment: Can we do unlimited scrolling? Because using the above code  it is scrolling but after reaching the last index it is moving to the first index (here collection view scrolling towards first index).